# Map<String, MyObject> in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I got a simple object defined as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="container")
public class Container{

      @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
      private Map<String, MyObject> myobject;
```

I am trying to deserialize/serialize it correctly using jaxb.

MyObject is a simple bean with two attributes "street" and "address" as String.

In stackoverflow I found examples on how to use jaxb with Map but in this case I want to use object MyObject.

MapAdapter is defined as

```
class MapElements {
@XmlAttribute
public String key;
@XmlElement
public MyObject value;

private MapElements() {
} //Required by JAXB

public MapElements(String key, MyObject value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public MyObject getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(MyObject value) {
    this.value = value;
}


}


public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapElements[], Map<String, MyObject>> {
public MapAdapter() {
}

public MapElements[] marshal(Map<String, MyObject> arg0) throws Exception {
    MapElements[] mapElements = new MapElements[arg0.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, MyObject> entry : arg0.entrySet()){
        mapElements[i++] = new MapElements(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return mapElements;
}

public Map<String, MyObject> unmarshal(MapElements[] arg0) throws Exception {
    Map<String, MyObject> r = new TreeMap<String, MyObject>();
    for (MapElements mapelement : arg0)
        r.put(mapelement.key, mapelement.value);
    return r;
}
}
```

but once I try to deserialize the object I got error

```
487:Can not set java.lang.String field com.company.mypackage.myservice.MapElements.key to [Lcom.company.mypackage.myservice.MapElements;
```

probably it is not possible to do in jaxb because it is strongly typed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered that I needed a XMLAdapter when I wanted to un/marshall a `Map`. But... it seems that this is not required for every server / JAXB implementation and sometimes this is even counterproductive. While the error message was not at all helpful to me, as soon as I removed the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` from the map it started working and it marshalled it as expected. So while this isn't really the answer to solve that message, it at least may help others that start with "I need a `XMLJavaTypeAdapter` for a `Map`" in mind, as I did.

So summarized: for some JAXB implementation you do not need the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`-annotation, nor do you need that `MapAdapter` or `MapElements`-class. It will just work out of the box.